# Rendering webforms controls in mvc: Why are Postback and Events not triggering correctly?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, webforms

So, like many people, I'm trying to migrate an old (and very large) webforms application to an MVC4 application. Because a rewrite is daunting (and realistically infeasible), I'm attempting to wrap the application in an MVC application. And from there we'll rewrite portions. I've got a fairly successful HtmlHelper extension that is rendering the old webforms controls. It looks like this:

```
public static MvcHtmlString RenderClassicControl(this HtmlHelper html, string controlPath)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        var stWriter = new StringWriter(sb);
        var htmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(stWriter);
        var page = new Page();
        page.PreInit += ((s, e) =>
        {
            var form = new HtmlForm();
            form.ID = "Form";
            form.Attributes.Add("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
            page.Controls.Add(form);
            var control = page.LoadControl(controlPath);
            form.Controls.Add(control);
            page.Controls.Add(form);
        });
        HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(page, htmlWriter, true);
        return new MvcHtmlString(sb.ToString());
    }
```

The problem I'm having is that, though the rendered html looks identical to the current site, when I complete an action on that control, nothing happens.  There are things in the request collection that I would expect to see (like __EVENTTARGET) but they're empty and isPostback is false. I expect that I'm missing something here, and I'm hoping somebody has some ideas. Thanks so much for taking the time!

Comment: Why are you converting it to MVC if you don't have time to do a rewrite? Is it because you want new development efforts on the site to use MVC? If so, the two can live side-by-side on the [same site](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntegratingASPNETMVC3IntoExistingUpgradedASPNET4WebFormsApplications.aspx). My guess as to why the post back isn't happening is because there's one more or JS files that WebForms relies on, but that aren't being referenced in your MVC page.

Comment: Certainly yes that, but also because I'm trying to ditch a very old version of DotNetNuke that was never implemented correctly and that hasn't been playing too well with .net 4

Comment: Why not convert the old webforms controls into MVC user controls and then render them as partial or Actions? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12714071/user-control-equivelnt-in-asp-net-mvc-4

Comment: Because the DotNetNuke framework I'm trying to replace uses a user control for every page. I literally don't have time to convert it all.

Comment: I guess I don't understand why MVC was even brought in. I would either continue using a version of the framework that works well enough with the version of DotNetNuke you have, or try to replace what you have with a newer version of ASP.NET Webforms. By going to MVC, you are trying to upgrade AND change architecture, doing both at the same time is very painful and should be avoided if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up taking Brian Ball's suggestion. All I did was add a default.aspx and masterpage and load my controls through that

Answer (score 0):

Webforms event driven environment. MVC action based. In web form you will have a helper javascript functions like `__doPostBack`, etc to take care of executing a correct event raised by a control

Webforms executes page life cycle and hook `__EVENTTARGET && __EVENTARGUEMENT` to match a currect event listener and fires it. This is totally different in MVC

Better start changing webform events to MVC controller action, and for data, post it to server and process in form of JSON or normal form data

Comment: Does HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(page, htmlWriter, true); not execute the whole page life cycle?

Comment: @JeffLauder, It may execute the handler mapped.But what about the post data like EVENTTARGET, etc to process the events? How you will get it.

Comment: I was under the impression that the last argument allows the passthrough of the System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request object. Is that not where the post data you are referring to is stored? Or does MVC modify it somehow?